# Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, error-handling

It gives the error: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

It says NoReverseMatch.

Tried replacing the url login with accounts:login and didn't work.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   <form id="logoutForm" action="/logout/" method="post" class="navbar-right">
     {% csrf_token %}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><span class="navbar-brand">Hello {{ user.username }}!</span></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
  </form>

{% else %}

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log in</a></li>
  </ul>

{% endif %}
```

My accounts app urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',
         LoginView.as_view
         (
             template_name='accounts/login.html',
             authentication_form=forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
             extra_context=
             {
                 'title': 'Log in',
                 'year' : datetime.now().year,
             }
         ),
         name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'), name='logout'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    ]
```

My main urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I don't know what to do about this, tried many stuff.

Comment: Did you try `path('account/', include('accounts.urls'))`

Comment: Did u mean accounts with an 's' ? that's my app name if so, ill try it

Comment: no i mean give a spesific path to your account urls. as of now, I think django is getting trouble redirecting the request as both home and accounts.urls are `path('')`

Answer (score 1):

**accounts/urls.py** file should add the **auth_views**:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',
         auth_views.LoginView.as_view
         (
             template_name='accounts/login.html',
             authentication_form=forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
             extra_context=
             {
                 'title': 'Log in',
                 'year' : datetime.now().year,
             }
         ),
         name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'), name='logout'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    ]
```

Please use the following code for login urls. Actually you are using the same route for two different urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: where do I use the same route?

Comment: DatGuy, after adding this:  `path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')), ` what are you getting. Any errors?

Comment: Have you copied all code which i suggested in the answer in `accounts/urls.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

ok got the solution. you were using

```
path('', include('accounts.urls')),
```

in main urls.py correct it to put a namespace

```
path('', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
```

and then correct the template

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Log in</a></li>
  </ul>
```